# Error running node, npm install pg error and gyp error

Tags: node.js, pg, node-gyp

When I run `node app.js`, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/jchan1/projects/versiv-api/node_modules/pg/lib/native/../../build/default/binding'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jchan1/projects/versiv-api/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:17:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Because the error above says something about `pg`, I do an `npm install pg`, but this is the error I get:

```
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ npm install pg
/
> pg@3.4.0 install /home/jchan1/projects/versiv-api/node_modules/pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 503 status code downloading tarball
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/jchan1/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:246:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onResponse (/home/jchan1/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (http.js:1692:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1587:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/jchan1/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/jchan1/projects/versiv-api/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
pg@3.4.0 node_modules/pg
├── packet-reader@0.2.0
├── pg-connection-string@0.1.1
├── buffer-writer@1.0.0
├── pg-types@1.4.0
├── generic-pool@2.0.3
├── nan@0.6.0
└── pgpass@0.0.3 (split@0.3.3)
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 using `node` v0.10.33, `python2.7`, and have `build-essentials`, `make`, and `g++` installed.

```
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ nvm list
       v0.10.25
->     v0.10.33
         system
default -> v0.10.33
node -> stable (-> v0.10.33) (default)
stable -> 0.10 (-> v0.10.33) (default)
iojs -> iojs- (-> N/A) (default)
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ npm -v
1.4.28
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ nodejs -v
v0.10.33
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ node -v
v0.10.33
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
jchan1@ubuntu ^___^V: $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: It says something about a `503 error` which means `Service unavailable`. Have you tried again? If not, try and come back with news.. (I just tried `npm install pg` with no errors)

Comment: I've tried again, and it's still isn't working. Seems like the `503` isn't temporary...

Comment: Do you have the same issue with other modules?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was running this in a VM using NAT. Once I switched to bridged mode, things worked. I suspect NAT didn't allow certain ports, which is why browser worked, but npm install didn't. Odd thing is that other modules installed correctly...

Comment: Are you running any service that uses http[s] port in your machine (not in the VM)?